# How can I securely authenticate to a server socket with java?

Tags: java, sockets, security, serversocket

I have written a java program, where a client connects to a server via socket (not SSLSocket!).
First the client creates an RSA-keypair and then sends the public key to the server. Then the server responds with a public key, which the client uses to create the RSA-encoded login password for authentication.

Is this a safe way or, if not, how can I ensure the security of the password?

Comment: While I would think that anything without SSL would be insufficient I would ask this on https://security.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would almost never implement a handshake protocol yourself unless you were an expert in cryptography.

Instead, since I can presume you're using a protocol like TCP, UDP, or HTTP, you can use libraries like Netty or just the built in TLS/SSL support.

[Netty SSL Example](https://github.com/devsunny/netty-ssl-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/asksunny/ssl/client/NettySocketClient.java)

[SSLSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html) (i know you said you didnt use it) class for no 3rd party usage.

Comment: But if I use SSL or SSLSocket I guess it is neccessary to have a certificate? Are there free possibilities out there or do they all cost money? I honestly have some trouble understanding how it works and I couldn't get an SSLSocket working in my tests. How do I get a certificate and how do I get a keystore?

Comment: Nah man you're set! Use LetsEncrypt! It's free, and lasts 90 days! Getting a certificate is easy, a keystore (or truststore) can be difficult.

Comment: Okay. Now two questions: How can I get a keystore and how do I create an authentication system with username and password? I searched a lot today but couldn't find a good overview.

Comment: That's more of a separate question for stack overflow, not me, sorry.